# How can I achieve this effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery

https://upperinc.com/previews/wp/swape/demo1

The second slide with the app UI images. The way they slide in and then the spacing changes when you hover over the slider. It looks like it's just three images inside of a div using some jquery effects. Is there a specific name for this effect? How can I find the code they're using for that effect when inspecting the source?

Answer (score 0):

The effect itself is just a simple `slideIn` in this particular it's a `slideInUp`. This site might use an own code but you can, if you wan't to keep it easy, use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

For animate.css-usage:

- Just add a `timeout` to the `.addClass`
- rezise the pictures
- give them a proper z-index or use the html-order to determine whats on the top

Comment: looks like I can combine it with jquery. Would I be better off just using jquery by itself? The animate CSS doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: In the end it's a collaboration between `css` and `js/jquery`. If you're using animate.css or not. You can of course, build your own transofrmation-css and achieve this effect.